Error while installing node_modules: Multiple deprecated packages and vulnerabilities
I've been encountering numerous warnings and errors during the npm install process for my project. I don't recall which package change caused this, but these issues have persisted. Below is a summary of the warnings and errors I get:
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.
npm warn deprecated stable@0.1.8: Modern JS already guarantees Array#sort() is a stable sort, so this library is deprecated. See the compatibility table on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#browser_compatibility
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-private-methods instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-numeric-separator instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-class-properties instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-catch-binding@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-catch-binding instead.
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator@7.18.6: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-nullish-coalescing-operator instead.
npm warn deprecated gulp-header@1.8.12: Removed event-stream from gulp-header
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-logical-assignment-operators instead.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@2.6.3: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated rollup-plugin-terser@7.0.2: This package has been deprecated and is no longer maintained. Please use @rollup/plugin-terser
npm warn deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining@7.21.0: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-optional-chaining instead.
npm warn deprecated rimraf@3.0.2: Rimraf versions prior to v4 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-async-generator-functions@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-async-generator-functions instead.
npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported
npm warn deprecated domexception@2.0.1: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
npm warn deprecated @babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread@7.20.7: This proposal has been merged to the ECMAScript standard and thus this plugin is no longer maintained. Please use @babel/plugin-transform-object-rest-spread instead.
npm warn deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm warn deprecated w3c-hr-time@1.0.2: Use your platform's native performance.now() and performance.timeOrigin.
npm warn deprecated sourcemap-codec@1.4.8: Please use @jridgewell/sourcemap-codec instead
npm warn deprecated workbox-cacheable-response@6.6.0: workbox-background-sync@6.6.0
npm warn deprecated workbox-google-analytics@6.6.0: It is not compatible with newer versions of GA starting with v4, as long as you are using GAv3 it should be ok, but the package is not longer being maintained
npm warn deprecated coffee-script@1.12.7: CoffeeScript on NPM has moved to "coffeescript" (no hyphen)
npm warn deprecated svgo@1.3.2: This SVGO version is no longer supported. Upgrade to v2.x.x.

I've tried running npm audit and npm update but the issues persist. Here are my project details:
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "2.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.16",
    "axios": "1.6.5",
    "firebase": "^10.12.2",
    "flowbite-react": "0.7.2",
    "postcss": "8.4.33",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "9.0.4",
    "react-router-dom": "6.21.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "9.1.3",
    "redux-persist": "6.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2"
  }


Basically: don't use Create React App.

Try removing the smaller packages first to see which one makes the error go away. Guessing it's one of the small packages pinned to a version like flowbite-react or @react-native-async-storage/async-storage or autoprefixer etc.

@C.Helling There dependencies were there before, Now after resolving as many things as possible, I am getting this error in most pages.
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /Users/nirmalpanchal/Work/Professional Service Plus/web-app/node_modules/react-refresh/runtime.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
You can either move it inside src/, or add a symlink to it from project's node_modules/.

That error seems pretty clear, fix your import of react-refresh
